# Parallax using jQuery on cordova phone gap app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, parallax

I have phone gap app created with html5. On the launch screen I have built a parralax theme. When I test this on chrome with [ripple](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) it works fine or just in chrome this works fine. However when I launch the app using cordova my device nothing happens when the page is scrolled.
Are scroll events handled differently with phone gap apps as they are in web browsers?

app.js

```
    var IntTimer = null;
var startHeader = function () {
    var container = $('#homeContent'), logo = $('#homeLogo'), bgImage = $('#homeSecondImage'), logoOverlay = $('#homeLogoCont');
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop() - 10;
    var logoMarginTop = $('#homePage').scrollTop() / 5.5;
    var logoMarginBottom = Math.floor($('#homePage').scrollTop() / 1.85);
    wScroll = (($('#homePage').scrollTop() - 20) < 0) ? 0 : $('#homePage').scrollTop();
    if((wScroll / 3) < 100){ //was 80
        //$('#homeAbout').css('background-color' , 'rgba(0,0,0,0.' + Math.ceil(wScroll / 3.5) + ')');
        bgImage.css('opacity', '0.' + Math.ceil(wScroll / 3.5));
        logoOverlay.css('opacity', '0.' + Math.ceil(wScroll / 3));
        if((wScroll / 3) < 15){
            logo.css('opacity', 1);
        } else{
            logo.css('opacity', '0.' + 100 - (Math.ceil(wScroll / 3.5)));
        }

    } else {
        bgImage.css('opacity', 1);
        logoOverlay.css('opacity', 1);
        logo.css('opacity', 0);
    }
    if($('#homePage').scrollTop() <= 322){
        logo.css('margin-top', 5 + logoMarginTop);
        logoOverlay.css('margin-top', 5 + logoMarginTop);
        logo.css('margin-bottom', 200 - logoMarginBottom);
        logoOverlay.css('margin-bottom', 200 - logoMarginBottom);
    }
    $('#homeScrollDir').attr('src', ($('#homePage').scrollTop() > 800) ? 'res/xhdpi/scrollup.png' : 'res/xhdpi/scrolldown.png');
};
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){  
    $('body').addClass('body-home');
        alert('PAGE CREATED');
        $('#homeContent').on('click',function () {
            alert('DO SOMETHING');
        });
    $('#homePage').on("scrollstart", function(){
        IntTimer = setInterval(startHeader, 2);
        alert('SCROLL START');
    });
    $('#homePage').on("scrollstop", function(){
        clearInterval(IntTimer);
        alert('SCROLL STOP');
    });
});
```

I am using HTML5, jquery and jquery mobile and phone gap to build the app if it helps. The homepage is my own HTML as I want this to be different.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage">
        <header></header>
        <div id="homeContent" data-role="content" class="content">
            <div id="homeContainer"  class="row">
                <div class="12u 12u(small) center"><img id="homeLogo" src="res/xhdpi/icetvlogo.png" /></div>
                <div class="clear homeSpace"></div>
                <div class="2u 1u(xsmall)">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="8u 10u(xsmall)">
                    <form id="login">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        <a href="#"><div class="button fit">Log In</div></a>
                    </form>
                    <a href="#"><div class="button alt fit">Sign Up</div></a>
                </div>
                <div class="2u 1u(xsmall)">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div id="homeSecondImage"></div>
            <div id="homeAbout" class="row">
                <div class="2u 1u(xsmall)">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="8u 10u(xsmall)">
                    <div class="button altwhite fit">About IceTV</div>
                    <p>DUMMY TEXT</p>
                    <p>DUMMY TEXT</p>
                </div>
                <div class="2u 1u(xsmall)">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll_down">
            <img id="homeScrollDir" src="res/xhdpi/scrolldown.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#homePage{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
#homePage *{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#homePage #homeContent{
    width:100%;
    height:200vh;
    position:relative;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; 
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; 
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; 
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; 
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}
#homePage #homeLogo{
    width:50%;
    max-width:200px;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    margin-bottom:200px;
}
#homeContainer, #homeSecondImage, #homeAbout{
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#homeContainer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:0px;
    height:100vh;
}
#homeSecondImage{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    height:100vh;
}
#homeAbout{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:100vh;
    height:100vh;
}
#homeAbout p{
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:0.85em;
}
.scroll_down{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0.5em;
    left:50%;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    -ms-transform:translateX(-50%); 
    -o-transform:translateX(-50%); 
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%); 
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%); 
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    z-index:99;
}
.scroll_down img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Images:
[image: header image]

[image: client logo]

[image: scroll down]

[image]

> Update - I think the problem is with the scroll functions themselves I added some alerts to the scrollstart and scrollstop functions and they never get called.

Comment: Would you be willing to upload your image assets?  I've built a brand new project using your code, but not seeing the images - I wonder if I'm not seeing the right effect(s).